# Calling _chkstk manually

Tags: c++, visual-studio, inline-assembly

I have performance critical algorithm and implemented it with inline assembly, it resulted in 40% performance gain so I want keep and use it, however there is one issue.

I use [naked declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs.aspx), that leaves everything up to me and compiler doesn't add anything in function scope. My function looks like this:

```
bool __declspec(naked) Foo(...)
{
    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 0x10000

        /*some code here*/

        ret
    }
}
```

As you see I have 64KB of locals, so it can crash because of stack corruption. That compiler does, it inserts calls to [_chkstk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648426(v=vs.85).aspx) routine which expands stack.

As I searched there are some files with this routine implemented:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio [version]\VC\crt\src\intel\chkstk.asm
```

I would like to ask how can I import and use routine from there and if there is another way of preventing crashes.

What I can think about is adding my own implementation, something like that:

```
mov ecx, 0x10
guard_page_testing_starts:
test [esp], eax
sub esp, 0x1000
dec ecx
jnz guard_page_testing_starts
```

But here is another question, does it have any negative impact?

Comment: It does *not* expand stack, it merely tries to intentionally generate a stackoverflow exception.  Ensuring there is a memory read every 4096 bytes so it will always hit the guard page and trigger the exception.  Technically it is possible for code to access memory beyond the stack boundary without that triggering an SOE.  Very unusual, big messy impossible to diagnose bug when that happens.  And exploitable.  Fwiw, if you want chkstk with that prologue then there is no remaining reason to use naked.

Comment: To add to @Hans Passant's answer: Windows places a 4kB guard page at the top of the stack. Writing to the guard page triggers a harmless CPU exception; it's this exception which tells Windows to grow the stack by another 4kB and moves the guard page to the new top of stack. This logic works regardless of the programming language used. `_chkstk` is used by VC++ so all locals can be initialized in any order.